# how to define value from within the function call

Tags: javascript

I have this function call:

```
<a href="javascript;;" onclick="helloWorld(value="planet")">
```

and then this function

```
function helloWorld(value) {
  return value
}
```

Obv, it doesn't work. I need to be able to set the value of value from within the `onclick`. Is this possible in js?

Comment: you dont need onclick="helloWorld(value="planet")" instead do onClick="helloWorld('planet')"

Comment: @Yeak but then how do I access it within the function helloWorld?

Comment: in your function value will equal to 'planet' - add a console.log(value) in your helloWorld function and look at the browser console and you will see it print out

Comment: @devdude19289 exactly how you are. `value` is the `value` in the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value that you are passing is known as `arguments` and the placeholder that is receiving the value is known as `parameter`.

So whatever you pass arguments gets assigned to a placeholder (i.e to parameter) in this case it is `value`

So you have defined a function who accept a parameter, so all you have to do is call it with single argument.

```js
function helloWorld(value) {
  return value
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript;;" onclick="helloWorld('planet')"> link </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call your function with `return` to `value` it means result of `helloWorld('planet')` will be your `value`, in this case `planet`. When you pass argument to functions you just need to put in correct order, you do not need to define them with `=`.

Let's say you have function with 3 values like this

```
function test(value1, value2, value3) {
   return value1+value2+value3
}
```

you need to just respect to order `test(5,2,1)` to identify each value

```js
function helloWorld(value) {
  console.log(value)  //Here as you can see you already have acces to it
  return value //Also here when you call this function it return to value it means, result of helloWorld('anyString') will be your value
}
```

```html
<a onclick=helloWorld("planet")>
TEST
</a>
```